# Python pandas replacing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Current dataframe

```
id, date, quantity
1,2017-08-01,22
2,1900-01-01,31
3,2017-08-01,44
4,2017-08-02,12
5,1900-01-01,22
6,1900-01-01,31
7,2017-08-02,44
8,2017-08-03,12
```

Desired output

```
id, date, quantity
1,2017-08-01,22
2,2017-08-01,31
3,2017-08-01,44
4,2017-08-02,12
5,2017-08-02,22
6,2017-08-02,31
7,2017-08-02,44
8,2017-08-03,12
```

There's only a few in the data that I just used set_value and did it manually, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with a method.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Zero the dates!

Comment: @Zero dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `1900-01-01` with `np.nan` and then `.ffill()`

```
df['date'] = df['date'].replace('1900-01-01',np.nan).ffill()
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   id        date  quantity
0   1  2017-08-01        22
1   2  2017-08-01        31
2   3  2017-08-01        44
3   4  2017-08-02        12
4   5  2017-08-02        22
5   6  2017-08-02        31
6   7  2017-08-02        44
7   8  2017-08-03        12
```

Comment: Hi! @bernie (-:

Comment: @bernie this works!! reading through the documentation now.  Didn't know about bfill/ffill. Thanks!!

Comment: @JeremyWu: you're very welcome. We're definitely spoiled by pandas' rich API.